# Адаптировать изображение CSS

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, есть див в котором находится изображение и див с текстом, как сделать, чтобы высота изображения автоматически подстраивалась под высоту второго дива с текстом? Ну и естественно, чтобы изображение не растягивалось только по высоте, но и по ширине подгонялось. Заранее спасибо

```css
.new {
display: flex;
align-items: center;
}
```

```html
<div class="new">
  <img src="img/news.png" alt="news">
  <div class="right-new">
    <p>1 hour ago</p>
    <h3>New startup idea loremsu ipsumers
    <br>Lorem ipsum lorem them startuping</h3>
    <p>by <span>Kadir</span></p>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: aspect-ratio играет довольно таки большую роль и к примеру если количество текста перевалит то получается что ваше изображение растянется - что будет как минимум Шляпа , Вы же понимаете что изображение бывают Вертикальные Горизонтальные и Квадратные ? Вот как поступать в этом случае ? Эту задачу не возможно решить

Comment: @НикитаФаст, хром с тобой не согласен. Да и у меня тоже несколько мыслей есть, но какие-то они жутко сложные.

Comment: @НикитаФаст, давайте [продолжим обсуждение в чате](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/84697/discussion-between-qwertiy-and--).

Answer (score -1):

Через грид работает в хроме, в Edge и FF не работает:

```css
main {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 1fr;
}

img {
  height: 100%;
}

main {
  border: 1px dotted red;
  margin: 1em;
}

section :first-child {
  margin-top: 0;
}

section :last-child {
  margin-bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/5NiXj.jpg">
  <section>
    <p>1 hour ago</p>
    <h3>New startup idea loremsu ipsumers
    <br>Lorem ipsum lorem them startuping</h3>
    <p>by <span>Kadir</span></p>
  </section>
</main>

<main>
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/5NiXj.jpg">
  <section>
    <p>1 hour ago</p>
  </section>
</main>

<main>
  <img src="//i.stack.imgur.com/5NiXj.jpg">
  <section>
    <p>1 hour ago</p>
    <h3>New startup idea loremsu ipsumers
    <br>Lorem ipsum lorem them startuping</h3>
    <p>by <span>Kadir</span></p>
    <p>1 hour ago</p>
    <h3>New startup idea loremsu ipsumers
    <br>Lorem ipsum lorem them startuping</h3>
    <p>by <span>Kadir</span></p>
    <p>1 hour ago</p>
    <h3>New startup idea loremsu ipsumers
    <br>Lorem ipsum lorem them startuping</h3>
    <p>by <span>Kadir</span></p>
  </section>
</main>
```

Comment: Желательно кроссбраузерное решение

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев уточните в тексте вопроса, насколько кроссбраузерное

Comment: хотя бы, чтобы работало более чем в 1 браузере :)

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев, так я ж не проверял, в скольки оно работает. Может и во всех современных. SO в своей разметке уже давно вовсю гриды использует.

Comment: И вообще, за что минус-то?

Comment: @ПавелРумянцев, ладно, проверил, действительно только хром.

Answer (score -1):

```css
.new {
display: flex;
align-items: stretch;
}
```

Comment: Так вообще не работает.